# How to get response time with RestEasy client

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy

I'm using a `ResteasyClientBuilder` to build an Http Client and I would like to log the response time of each request.

I tried using Request/Response filters to measure the time, problem is that I'm building the client with `connectionPoolSize(1)` and have multiple Threads using the client concurrently, so the time measured by the filters includes the time waiting for the connection to be free.

How can I get the pure request response time?

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using?

Comment: Version 4.5.9 I think

Comment: Maybe this will help https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.5.9.Final/userguide/html/Tracing_Feature.html